# how can i get blockchain private key using just my wallet address

Tags: e-wallet

Please i can get a  private key using the 12 phrases of my wallet using Bip32 but how can i get my wallet private key without the phrases and just having the wallet address

Comment: You cannot get the private key from the bitcoin address. No way. Maybe be a bit more specific, so help is possible. This question was already marked as „unclear“. What wallet you use, for what reason you need the privkeys extracted, maybe there are solutions to your demand on a different way.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what is supposed to not be possible and gives value to the blockchain. So, unless you have an advanced quantum computer at your disposal I'm afraid you will not be able to do it.

Comment: what is a quantum computer helping here? Is ECDSA (privkey -> pubkey) not quantum save? From what I have read, I understand encryption is in danger, but haven't read about ECDSA and Hash256/RipeMD. Are there any links?

Comment: It was a tongue-in-cheek reference/joke. But yes, the rumors say that as soon as quantum computers with 100 Q-Bits exist, the first types of encryption will become crackable.